# How to optimize a socket?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is it possible to reduce the weight of socket traffic and speed it up? What are the options for socket optimization? For now I don't want to use other libraries/languages

Sockets work in threads, maybe there is another option to optimize threads?

Right now I'm using the standard functions

```
import threading, socket
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(('ip', port))
def myfunc():
    s.send(b"\x00\x00")
    s.recv(4096)
thread1 = threading.Thread(target=myfunc)
thread1.start()
```

Comment: Please add your [mcve] showing your code and describing what you are trying to transfer, and how.

Comment: there are lots of things you can do, like switch between udp or tcp, various tcp knobs,  sending data in bulk, changing encodings.  you really have to clarify what your use case is, and where you are currently for anyone to suggest any improvements.

Comment: please add yor example code For better help .

Comment: the example doesn't give any more detail into the problem that you want to speed up.   one obvious issue is that you might be blocking the sending on the recving, so you could switch to non blocking or use a select call.